# Django (CSRF token missing or incorrect) suppress logging

Tags: django, logging

In our webapplication it's pretty common that users accidentally open the login page in multiple tabs and trigger the "CSRF token missing or incorrect" error in Django.

I would like to suppress this specific message in our logging, because it generates a lot of noise and the issue isn't really fixable.
On the other hand, any other issue in the login process should be logged, so I would not want to exclude a whole Django app or class from logging.

Do you have any suggestions on how to suppress this specific common error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per official  [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/#django-security-logger) you can update your `LOGGING` settings this:

```
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.security.csrf': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to suppress this particular error, but still log other CSRF-related errors, it gets a bit tricky.

The CSRF module uses the logger named `django.security.csrf`. The message is logged in the [`_reject` method of the `CsrfViewMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b3f1c35dd848678225e8634d6880efeeab5e796/django/middleware/csrf.py#L150). You could add a filter to that logger that filters out log records with that error reason in the args. That would look something like this:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import REASON_BAD_TOKEN

def missing_token_filter(record):
    return REASON_BAD_TOKEN not in record.args

LOGGING = {
   ...,
   'handlers': {
       ...
       'django.security.csrf': {
           'filters': ['missing_token_filter']
       }
   },
   'filters': {
       ...,
       'missing_token_filter: {
           '()': 'path.to.missing_token_filter',
       },
}
```